# Cross subdomain css rule inspection

Tags: javascript, html, css, nginx, cors

I would like to do the following:

From my page at `https://www.example.com/index.html`,

1. Load a style sheet found at `https://staticfiles.example.com/main.css`,
2. Inspect (and ultimately edit) the rules found in this sheet once loaded via javascript using the  `document.stylesheets` array.

However, when I try this I find that each `CSSStyleSheet` object contained in `document.stylesheets` has `null` where I would expect to find my list of rules.

These rules can be found as expected when I load the stylesheet from `https://www.example.com/styles/main.css`, so the issue I believe is something to do with cross-origin resource sharing.

In an attempt to solve this problem I have tried adding this:

`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://www.example.com;`

to my Nginx configuration file affecting everything served from `staticfiles.example.com`, but sadly with no success.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using https for both subdomains, right?

Comment: I was indeed, the difficulties were due to the Access Control Allow Origin permissions. In the end I settled on generating the CSS dynamically via a template server site based on some variables in the url which is arguably a better solution anyway.